# R: How to use "NOT IN" logic in R

Tags: sql, r

How can I convert below sql query to R Logic:

`SELECT * FROM FRUITS WHERE (ID||TYPE||DATE) NOT IN (SELECT (ID||TYPE||DATE) FROM SEASONAL_FRUITS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIth `tidyverse`, it would be anti join

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(FRUITS, SEASONAL_FRUITS, by = c("ID", "TYPE", "DATE"))
```